# How to add python library using a PythonRecipe(python-for-android)?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, python-for-android

I use a buildozer to get the *APK* file. I have added my desired library to *.spec file. But the application didn't open on Android mobile. I debugged with code `adb logcat *:S python:D`.I noticed that one of the libraries wasn't working properly.So I want to use *PythonRecipe* to add this library.
I wrote the following code according to this [site](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/):

```
from pythonforandroid.recipe import PythonRecipe
class ArabicReshaperRecipe(PythonRecipe):
    url = 'https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper/archive/master.zip'

    depends = ['python3', 'numpy','sys','unittest']

    site_packages_name = 'arabic_reshaper'

recipe = ArabicReshaperRecipe()
```

But I don't know where to put this file and what to name it!